# R plotl_ly: Points of time data different color (past data lighter, current data darker)

Tags: r, colors, timestamp, time-series, plotly

I need some help for plotting time data. My data frame is defined as the following:

```
date <- c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2020-01-01", 
          "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10", "2020-05-15")
prod1 <- c(43.10, 42.56, 41.77, 41, 40.79, 41.03, 40.98, 41.13, 41.98, 40.81)
prod2 <- c(19.442, 19.320, 19.204, 18.918, 19.041, 19.452, 19.516, 19.177, 18.974, 19)
df.dataCorrelation <- data.frame(date, prod1, prod2)
```

The graph looks like this:

[image: timestamp]

What I want now is that the points from 2018 are lighter in color than the points from 2019, and so on. That is, the more up-to-date the data, the stronger/darker the color.

**Does anyone know how I could do that?** In reality, my data frame is much larger and contains a lot more information per year.

**EDIT: regression line**

```
fit <- lm(prod2 ~ prod1, data = df.dataCorrelation)
fitData <- data.frame((prod1 = 20:60))
prediction <- predict(fit, fitData, se.fit = TRUE)
fitData$fitted <- prediction$fit
```

Code for plotting:

```
df.dataCorrelation$Year <- format(as.Date(df.dataCorrelation$date), '%Y')

plotCorr <- plot_ly(data = df.dataCorrelation, x = ~prod1, y = ~prod2, color = ~Year, colors = "Greens",
                    marker = list(size = 10, line = list(color = "black", width = 2))) %>%
            add_trace(data = fitData, x = ~prod1, y = ~fitted, mode = "lines", type = "scatter", 
                      line = list(color = "#007d3c", width = 3))
```

**How can I plot the regression line?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked around the `plotly` documentation and opacity is possible when you add the data as individual traces. I tried to do that but the main idea of the plot is lost. I would suggest an approach where you can set colors by year. Here the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
#Data
date <- c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2020-01-01", 
          "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10", "2020-05-15")
prod1 <- c(43.10, 42.56, 41.77, 41, 40.79, 41.03, 40.98, 41.13, 41.98, 40.81)
prod2 <- c(19.442, 19.320, 19.204, 18.918, 19.041, 19.452, 19.516, 19.177, 18.974, 19)
df.dataCorrelation <- data.frame(date, prod1, prod2,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Extract year
df.dataCorrelation$Year <- format(as.Date(df.dataCorrelation$date),'%Y')
#Plot
plot_ly(data = df.dataCorrelation, x = ~prod1, y = ~prod2,color=~Year,
        marker = list(size = 10,
                      line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                  width = 2)))
```

Output:

[image]

I hope that can be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but unfortunately plotting the regression line doesn't work. The error message for plotting the regression line is: ```Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env): Object 'Year' not found```
I have now modified and added my code above with the plot and regression line. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @Michi Hi Michi, there is a way to do, in your data frame create a new variable with the fitted values and add it to the plot with `add_trace()` or `add_lines()`. `plotly` can be troublesome about this kind of things!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ggplotly` to make use of `ggplot` aesthetics:

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( plotly )
df.dataCorrelation$year <- format(as.Date(df.dataCorrelation$date), format="%Y")

p <- ggplot(df.dataCorrelation, aes(x = prod1, y = prod2)) +
    geom_point( aes(col = year) ) +
    geom_smooth( method = "lm", se = FALSE )

plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I need to use the ```plot_ly()``` function to illustrate the graphic.